# What is the meaning of open intervals in (0, 1]?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, borel-sets, borel-measures

I come from an engineering background, so my knowledge of measure theory is very bad. Please pardon me for asking this silly question.

Let $\Omega = (0,1]$ be the set. And I have to build a Borel-sigma algebra for $\Omega$. So at first, I have to define the collection of all open intervals in the set $(0, 1]$. Therefore, I have to ask what the meaning of open intervals in $(0, 1]$?
What is the collection of all open intervals in the set $(0, 1]$ look like?

My intuition says that the collection of all the open intervals in $(0, 1]$ denoted by $\mathcal{C}$ looks like

$$\mathcal{C}:=\{(a, b) : 0 \leq a < b \leq 1\}\cup \{(a, 1] : 0 \leq a<1\}$$

Please correct me if my notion of open intervals in $(0, 1]$ is wrong.

Comment: Your intuition is correct.

Comment: It depends on the topology. Your collection $C$ is good but incomplete, you can also have that $(a,1]$ is open in $\Omega$ (in the usual topology) for any $0\le a\lt1$

Comment: The root of your question is probably comments from another question you asked yesterday. And again, you need to define what means *open in $(0,1]$*. It is not a question of intuition but of definition. $(0,1]$ is open in $(0,1]$ for the relative topology and it is an interval. By the way any interval $(a,1]$ with $0 \lt a \lt 1$ is open in $(0,1]$.

Comment: @geetha290krm , No, my intuition is wrong. As pointed out by FShrike  , $(a, 1]$ is an open interval in $(a, 1]$ for any $0\leq a < 1$.

Comment: 'Open interval in $(a,1]$' is ambiguous. It can mean two different things.

Comment: @geetha290krm : Suppose I have to build a Borel-sigma algebra from the set $(0 , 1]$. In order to do that, I have to define what an open interval in the set $(0, 1]$ looks like. Do you have any suggestions about how I should define the collection of all open intervals in the set $(0, 1]$. Also, I have changed the notion of open intervals in $(0, 1]$ in my original question. Please have a look.

Comment: You should talk about open sets and open **balls** in $(0,1]$ (considered as a metric space in its own right), in which case what FShirike says is correct. But it is natural to interpret an open interval in $(0,1]$ as an open interval in $\mathbb R$ which is a subset of $(0,1]$.

Comment: @geetha290krm ; Everyone is giving me different answers.

Answer (score 1):

In general, if you have a *topological space* $X$ and a *subset* $Y$ of $X$, you turn $Y$ into a topological space by saying that the open subsets of $Y$ are the sets of the form $U \cap Y$ with $U$ an open subset of $X$.

In your case, the topology on $(0,1]$ is inherited from that on ${\mathbb R}$ and the open subsets of $(0,1]$ are the sets of the form $U \cap (0,1]$ with $U$ an open subset of ${\mathbb R}$.

In particular, this means that $(a,b)$ with $a,b \in [0,1]$ and $a < b$ is an open subset of $(0,1]$ since it is equal to $(a,b) \cap (0,1]$; it also means that $(a,1]$ with $a \in (0,1)$ is an open subset of $(0,1]$ since it is equal to $(a,2) \cap (0,1]$.

Comment: And what about the intervals $\{(a, b) : 0 \leq a < b \leq 1\}$? Are they open in $(0, 1]$?

Comment: Yes, those as well; I've updated the answer.