# How is set $(0.5, 1]$ is an open subset of $(0, 1]$?

Tags: general-topology

A set $A\subset \mathbb{R}$ is called open if $\forall x\in A$, there exist a $\delta > 0$, such that the interval $(x-\delta, x+\delta)\in A$. Now, we have the set $(0.5, 1]$, which is clearly a subset of $(0, 1]$ but $(0.5, 1]$ itself is not an open interval. To see this consider $x= 1$, then $\forall \delta >0$, $(1-\delta, 1+\delta)\not\subset (0.5, 1] $.
However, in answer to my previous question, people have said that $(0.5, 1]$ is open in $(0, 1]$. I don't understand why they are saying this. Can anyone help me understand what I am missing?

Comment: Context matters.  Presumably we are meant to consider the topology on $(0,1]$ induced by inclusion into $\mathbb R$.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the meaning of open intervals in (0, 1\]?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4520797/what-is-the-meaning-of-open-intervals-in-0-1) (This is your own question?!)

Comment: To stress:  it is necessary to specify which topology you are using.  Sets which are open in one topology might be closed in another, and so on.

Comment: @lulu ; I dont understand what topology means.

Comment: Since you don't understand what topology means, and since topology is necessary to answer your question, a good strategy for you would be to start with a basic book such as Munkres' book entitled "Topology".

Comment: @RobinKurtz The idea is that the half open interval $(0,1]$ is the entire universe. When we consider an open interval around $1$ we mean $\{x\in (0,1]: \lvert x-1\rvert\lt\delta\} $ for some $\delta\gt 0$.

Comment: If you don't know what topology means, then you can't solve this problem.  [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_topology) is an introduction.

Comment: @lulu ; How much time, on average it takes to learn topology?

Comment: The basic concepts are easy enough...reading the wikipedia page and thinking about it should take an afternoon. Going through the (excellent) book by Munkres (recommended by another user) takes longer.